# Is there any specific reason to use Amazon SNS instead of direct Baidu service

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, baidu

I have created push notification using Baidu. It works well through Baidu console and I receives the notification in my Android mobile.
I have to create a webservice to send push message from my specific application by using the SDK provided by Baidu. I have another option which seems to be available under Amazon SNS. It seems like a wrapper to Baidu, GCM etc.

My doubt is is there any specific advantage for using Amazon SNS over the Baidu provided SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tldr;**

If you target the chinese market only and Baidu is working well for you and you have all you code setup to work with Baidu, then **stay with Baidu**

**Some other points to clarify about Amazon SNS**

[Baidu cloud push](http://push.baidu.com/) offers a really good service if you want to send notification on the chinese market

[Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) on the other side is a much larger offering and as part of the [Mobile Push Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html) Amazon will act as an abstract layer and you can choose which implementation you want.

It has the following advantages:

- You are not limited to Baidu scope so you can send notification on the chinese market but not only and if/when needed to send a notification abroad it will be much easier without rewriting the whole thing
- You can use the same code and change quickly the provider for push notification in case the provider does not work at a given time (downtime operations) or if the conditions change and you're not happy with new conditions.

> You send push notification messages to both mobile devices and
>   desktops using one of the following supported push notification
>   services:
>
> - Amazon Device Messaging (ADM)
> - Apple Push Notification Service (APNS)    for both iOS and Mac OS X
> - **Baidu Cloud Push (Baidu)**
> - Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM)
> - Microsoft Push Notification Service for    Windows Phone (MPNS)
> - Windows Push Notification Services (WNS)
>
> The following figure shows an overview of how Amazon SNS is used to
>   send a direct push notification message to a mobile endpoint.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I stick to Baidu as I've the scope limited only inside Chinese market